# Node Type info from a namedDecl() matcher

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm-clang

I'm writing an open-source misra-c rule checker using the clang-frontend libraries.
Is there a way to get the type of a
node(FieldDecl,RecordDecl,FunctionDecl,...) that I've matched with a
namedDecl() matcher?

Comment: Depending on your type you should probably use [getTypeForDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TypeDecl.html#a84a2dafb93379e1b892012e92193d3a7) or [getType](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ValueDecl.html#a673ae4e2fab42426820de8df166fef5d)

Comment: those are for types e.g. `int`, `long int`,... . I can't get what kind of node i have matched using those.